# read from a txt file with encoding= cp1256

Tags: python, file-handling

I am trying to read and extract data from a file with encoding =cp1256
I can read the file and print all the information form it, but if I tried to search for something using the line.startswith it is not working

```
printing = False
with open(SourceFile,"r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("NODes\n"): # search for a keyword
            printing = True
            continue # go to next line
        elif line.startswith(";CON"):
            printing = False
            break #quit file reading
        if printing:
            print(line, file=PointsFile)
PointsFile.close()
```

it is only working if I save the file using the notepad and change the encoding to utf-8
the same code works fine
what should I do to make it works without changing the encoding

Answer (score 2):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) has optional argument `encoding`, [codecs - Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) shows table of encodings, as `cp1256` is one of them it should suffice to replace

```
with open(SourceFile,"r") as file:
```

using

```
with open(SourceFile,"r",encoding="cp1256") as file:
```

Comment: Hi I think you did not get my question, the thing is the file has a line starts with "NODes\n" 
but when the code is running nothing happens it create the pointsFile put there is no data inside  it is empty, but if I save the file (in my case it is an .str file ) as a txt file with encoding of utf-8 it will work